# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in a html file

Tags: javascript, json

when finding the length of an array of a json variable in javascript am getting the following error. **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**.
I am deploying my application in tomcat server. can anyone please help me to overcome this

Comment: How you array variable is defined? If var arr; then you call arr.length will lead to this exception. If var arr = []; you will not get any exception. But maybe there is problem in code and array is not defined.

Comment: var sample= jsonobject ['array defined in json file'];   for(var i = 0; **i<sample.length**;i++).   i am getting error in the bold section. @Alexandr

Comment: what is the result of console.log(sample)?

Answer (score 0):

This means you are setting sample to undefined. Whatever logic you are using to initialize sample is failing silently. If you post the real code you are using to initialize sample we can explain more.